# Can I create an attribute without relation with DB Table in a Entity?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

Can I create an attribute without relation with DB Table in a Entity ?

If it can, which annotation should I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes that are part of a persistent entity but not intended to be persistent can either be modified
with the transient modifier in Java or be annotated with the @Transient annotation.